# Clickable Span onClick not called in EditText

Tags: android, spannablestring

I am trying to create a chat screen and implement `@` based user annotation inside the message. For which I implmented a ClickableSpan class on the span.There are 3 parts to this problem. 
1) While sending the message (inside my EditText), any user annotations a user clicks on should take them to end of the annotation. Example - while typing **"@my_user@ this is a sample message"**, if a user touches around _ the cursor should be set at the end of @my_user@|

2) Sent message bubble - annotation should be clickable

3) Received Message bubble - annotation should be clickable

In my case 2. and 3. in the TextView are working. I need to understand what should I do to get 1 to work

Code below:->

> Setting the span

```
editable.setSpan(new UserAnnotationClickableSpan(editable.toString().substring(style.getStart() + keywordLength, style.getEnd() - keywordLength + 1)) , style.getStart() + keywordLength, style.getEnd() - keywordLength + 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

> UserAnnotationClickableSpan class

```
private class UserAnnotationClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan{
        String text;
        public UserAnnotationClickableSpan(String text){
            this.text = text;
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(Config.LOGTAG, "Clickable area called in text box");
            Spanned s;
            boolean isEditing = false;
            EditMessage em;
            TextView tv;
            // Notify clickable span handler
            if(view instanceof EditMessage){ // then user it typing.
                isEditing = true;
                em = (EditText) view;
                s = (Spanned) em.getText();
                int start = s.getSpanStart(this);
                int end = s.getSpanEnd(this);
                em.setSelection(end);

            }else { // its either a
                tv = (TextView) view;
                s = (Spanned) tv.getText();
                int start = s.getSpanStart(this);
                int end = s.getSpanEnd(this);
                String str = tv.getText().toString().trim();
                Log.d(Config.LOGTAG, "Clicked annotation is : " + text);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: did you set string to edittext after setting span to it?

Comment: yes did that!! all other properties of spannable are showing up.

Comment: is it working after changes?

Comment: what I meant was it was already, when I had replied to the previous comment

Comment: try using `youredittext.append("");` after setting your text.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to set cursor at the end

editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());

Comment: this will put the cursor at the end of the entire text. I want the cursor at the end of the span area. Also, the problem is while editing the onClick of the ClickableSpan is not getting called at all.